# Get redirected Wikipedia URL from original URL with Wikidata SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata

I have a list of Wikipedia URL's e.g.

```
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peninsular_War"
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_I_of_France"
```

etc.

Some of them directly redirect to other pages, for example, `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_I_of_France` redirects directly to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon`

I want to use the following SPARQL query for Wikidata  to obtain the corresponding Wikidata entities:

```sparql
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT ?url ?item WHERE {
        VALUES ?url {
 <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peninsular_War>
 <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_I_of_France>}

        ?url schema:about ?item.
        }
```

However, because of the redirection of the Napoleon URL, this query is unable to connect the URL with Napoleons's Wikidata entry. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using some programming language (like python)? Are you allowed to pre-process your URLs?

Comment: I am using JavaScript, but I would prefer a solution, which solely relies on SPARQL. Although every answer is appreciated, it must scale pretty fast with the amount of URLs. I am not sure if the MediaWiki API is capable of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia's redirects are not handled on Wikidata (except for [particular cases](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Sitelinks_to_redirects)), so I think you have to resolve possible redirects by pre-processing your URLs via API.

In your example, you can use the following query: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Napoleon_I_of_France&redirects

which gives you the binding

```
{
    "from": "Napoleon I of France",
    "to": "Napoleon"
}
```

But, in this case, I would directly use APIs instead of SPARQL for retrieving Wikidata items' IDs.

For example, the query:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects&titles=Napoleon_I_of_France
returns the desired ID [`Q517`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q517).

Note that the `titles` parameter accepts multiple titles!

For example, the query: [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects&titles=Peninsular_War|Napoleon_I_of_France](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects&titles=Peninsular_War%7CNapoleon_I_of_France) returns both `Q152499` and `Q517`.

This allows to drastically reduce the number of queries, which will be about `ceil(N/2048)`, where `N` is the total number of characters of your titles and `2048` is the standard maximum number of characters allowed in a single URL.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast answer. Unfortunately there is a limit on 50 items/pages per API call, 
which makes this option not really suitable for my use case. But thanks anyway! :)